# Auth0 getProfile does not return user_id

Tags: node.js, auth0

I am calling the node-auth0 sdk for my nodejs project.

```
auth0.getProfile(accessToken, function (err, userInfo) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err)
    }
    console.log(userInfo);
});
```

The userInfo returned does not contain user_id
[image]

What should I do if I want to get the user_id by access token?

Comment: please would you confirm my answer if it helped you solve your problem? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot, the `sub` claim (subject) is the `user_id`. Please confirm whether your expected `user_id` should be `facebook|1`.

You need to parse the String JSON object using

```
const userId = JSON.parse(userInfo)['sub'];
```

Here is working sample:

```
var AuthenticationClient = require('auth0').AuthenticationClient;

var auth0 = new AuthenticationClient({
  domain: '{TENANT}.auth0.com',
  clientId: '{client id}'
});

const accessToken = '{access token}';

auth0.getProfile(accessToken, function (err, userInfo) {
  const userId = JSON.parse(userInfo)['sub'];
  console.log(userId);
});
```

**FYI only** - Because you were dealing with a String object, when you called `sub` you were getting a reference to the deprecated [String `sub` prototype function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/sub)  Can understand the confusion. If you are unsure what type the Object is, a good way to check is something like `console.log(typeof userInfo);`

Comment: it displays the `user_id` value under the `sub` attribute. however, when I do `let yellerID = userInfo.sub;`, it gives me `function sub() { [native code] }`, which is assigned to the `yellerID` variable.

Comment: If I do `let yellerID = userInfo.sub()`, it gives me `<sub>{the object on the screenshot}</sub>`

Comment: I am using auth0 2.7.0

Comment: ok, located it - https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0/blob/58f9f6daf24b48ff32b8716891b784a0c0aa45a1/src/auth/index.js#L468

Comment: Yes, I am following this documentation: http://auth0.github.io/node-auth0/index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154907/discussion-between-ykn121-and-arcseldon).

Comment: @ykn121 - see solution above.

Comment: missed your idea to use chat.